# Show NSViewController from NSWindow

Tags: macos, nswindow, nsviewcontroller

The main window in my OS X app is based on a NSWindow. How do I show a popup view/window from a NSWindow?

I tried the following:

```
NSViewController* vc = [[NSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DialogConfirm" bundle:nil];
[self beginSheet:vc.view.window completionHandler: nil];
```

but vc.view.window is nil.

Comment: view.window is nil because it doesn't have one. So create an NSWindow, setup your view in the window, and then show that window.

Comment: So you suggest to create a new NSWindow and assign it to vc.view.window?

Comment: I'm suggesting that you create a new NSWindow, then add your NSView as a subview to window.contentView and then call [self beginSheet:window ...]

Comment: Thanks, it works. I found out that for my purpose it was better to use NSWindowControl with the method showWindow.